# Keyup event is not working on easyui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I have an issue with easyui textbox. I have this html

```
<input name="telefone" id="telefone" class="f1 easyui-textbox" data-options="required:true" />
```

And this js code:

```
$('#telefone').textbox({
            onChange:function(v){
                    var r = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
                    r = r.replace(/^0/,"");
                    if (r.length > 11) {
                        // 11+ digits. Format as 5+4.
                        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4}).*/,"($1)$2.$3-$4");
                    }
                    else if (r.length > 6) {
                        // 6..10 digits. Format as 4+4
                        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4}).*/,"($1)$2.$3-$4");
                    }
                    else if (r.length >= 3) {
                        // 3..5 digits. Add (0XX..)
                        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)(\d{0,5})/,"($1)$2.$3");
                    }
                    else {
                        // 0..2 digits. Just add (0XX
                        r = r.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
                    }

                    if (r != v) {
                        $('#telefone').textbox('setText',r);
                    }
                }
        });
```

This is working very well but onChange is working like onblur I would like it working like an onkeyup. So I tried this:

```
 $("#telefone").keyup(function() {
            alert("ok");
 });
```

And got no success =/

Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It'll definitely work.

```
$("#telefone").on("keyup", function()            { alert("ok"); })
```